Capacity vs Capability vs Ability
I'm having a hard time trying to understand the difference between these words: capacity, capability and ability.
What I've gathered so far is that "capacity" and "capability" basically mean "potential for doing sth", but what's exactly the difference between them? I've also met an opinion that "ability" is like a proven ability, sth you can do and probably have done, while "capability" is an unproven ability, sth you can do but have not done so in the past and might never do it. How true is it?
Here is how "capacity" was used in on of the videos I've watched recentle. Is it possible to use "capability" or "ability" instead of "capacity"?
"Kids are definitely trying to talk or at least my kids were when they were one. But because they are so limited in their capacity to actually produce the language, the linguistic gains that they are making for the first five, six, seven years of their life are 99% input."
I feel like it is possible, but then again, I can't grasp the difference.
I would be glad if someone kindly explained the nuances of meaning of "capacity", "capability" and "ability" and provided some examples. Thank you!

IMO 'capacity' is for the ability to handle incoming stuff, and 'capability' for generating the outgoing. So the quote's use of 'capacity' jars with me. Also 'ability' is more general than 'capability'.

Each of the words cited might be used as synonyms, or near-synonyms, in some cases, and not in others.

"In his capacity as chairman," addresses his abilities and duties expected for that function.
"In his capacity as chairman, he can review the agenda."

"His ability to be chairman," regards whether he meets requirements to be chairman.
"His ability to be chairman is questioned, since he lives in anther state."

"His capability as chairman," regards whether he carries out the functions well.
"His capability as chairman was questioned, since he ignores the agenda."


Note, though, that these words refer to many other concepts. For example:

Electrical capacity can refer to either the power that a circuit can carry (measured in watts), or the amount of charge stored (measured in farads) -- two very different concepts.
The capacity of a tank refers to its volume.
The capacity of a rope refers to the maximum weight it should bear.

